# Same value is predicted every time - Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, prediction, sklearn-pandas

I have tried many regression algorithms like Gradient Boosting, random forest, decision trees.
I have tried scaling using both minmax and standard scaler.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train=scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=scaler.transform(x_test)
to_predict=scaler.transform(to_predict)
```

Some values from X_train after scaling:

```
       [-5.80641310e-01, -5.15194242e-01, -4.57304981e-01],
       [-5.99982344e-01, -5.74535988e-01, -4.57304981e-01],
       [-5.99982344e-01, -5.74535988e-01, -4.57304981e-01],
       [ 5.08258952e-01,  1.02769113e+00,  9.71784878e-03],
       [-5.99982344e-01, -5.74535988e-01, -4.57304981e-01],
       [-5.84509517e-01, -5.74535988e-01, -4.57304981e-01],
       [-5.98048241e-01, -5.74535988e-01, -4.57304981e-01]
```

Some values from X_test after scaling:

```
       [-0.59998234, -0.57453599, -0.45730498],
       [ 0.97244379,  2.15518429, -0.02141701],
       [ 2.50812195,  2.74860174,  3.18547309],
       [ 0.33612374,  0.37493194, -0.05255186],
       [-0.43364944, -0.51519424, -0.43862407],
       [ 2.37273471,  2.57057651,  3.92025568]
```

Some values from data to be predicted after scaling:

```
       [ 10.46308958,   7.37725787,  18.92725594],
       [ 11.04912294,   8.2080423 ,  19.03934142],
       [ 12.04131803,   7.85199183,  19.96716011],
       [ 12.29468558,   7.85199183,  15.58337248],
       [ 13.15342753,   8.68277626,  19.99829496],
       [ 11.8053574 ,   8.32672579,  18.29833186],
       [ 10.82476694,   9.69158593,  21.86638628]
```

Gradient Boosting regression:

```
grad=GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=500,random_state=100,learning_rate=1,max_depth = 10,min_samples_leaf =3,min_samples_split = 12)
grad.fit(x_train,y_train)

mae test: 0.03380270193992188
mse test: 0.0025669439864247356
rmse test: 0.05066501738304977
r2 test: 0.80834162616979
mae train: 0.02458157407407408
mse train: 0.0025056432439638046
rmse train: 0.05005640062932816
r2 train: 0.815567744395517
```

Some test set predictions:  -0.09690972, -0.09690972, -0.09690972,  0.14249752

Some train set predictions: -0.11616   ,  0.068165  ,  0.048538  ,-0.09690972

Some predictions for data that was to be predicted: 0.124851  ,  0.124851  ,  0.124851  ,
0.124851

The trained model works well for the train and test sets but predicts same constant for the rows I need prediction for. Maybe because the scaled train and test values have the same order but the data for which I want to use the model has very high values. I don't know how to solve this issue.

If I change the tuning parameters, the prediction just shifts to a different constant. This happens for all the regression algorithms I've tried. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: So, you have train data, test data and a totally different dataset that you'd like your model to predict on ? This third dataset comes from a different data distribution?

Comment: Also, my request to you is - rephrase the question to be a bit more understandable by a third person. Including the code you've tried would be of great help.

Comment: @achow the third dataset does not have a different distribution. Train and test are for different months than the third dataset.